# Tabs moving body

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

It's my first time trying semantic-ui.

I came across this issue:

[GIF Showing the issue](https://vgy.me/896Kj2.gif)

My tabs make the body moves, that's pretty annoying and I can't find any solutions. I took a look at the doc, and even there some examples are broken :/

HTML:

```
<div class="ui middle aligned center aligned grid">
<div class="column">
    <h2 class="ui teal image header">
        <img src="app/assets/images/logo.png" class="image">
        <div class="content">
            Log-in to your P4$Q account
        </div>
        <img src="app/assets/images/logo.png" class="image">
    </h2>
    <div class="ui large form">
        <div class="ui segment" style="background-color: #2b2b2b;">
            <div class="ui secondary pointing menu">
                <a class="active item" data-tab="first">
                    Home
                </a>
                <a class="item" data-tab="second">
                    Messages
                </a>
                <a class="item" data-tab="third">
                    Friends
                </a>
                <div class="right menu">
                    <a class="ui item">
                        Logout
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui bottom attached active tab segment" data-tab="first">
                First
            </div>
            <div class="ui bottom attached tab segment" data-tab="second">
                Second
            </div>
            <div class="ui bottom attached tab segment" data-tab="third">
                Third
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Best regards

Comment: can you provide the CSS and JS also, if possible a working example in JSFiddle?

Comment: Sure, there you go: https://jsfiddle.net/8v62s5q6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the fiddle. Please find below the working JSFiddle.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

The problem is that, the stylesheet `sematic.min.css` is adding below class shown below.

```
.ui.segment[class*="bottom attached"]:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Which is removing the margin for the last element alone. Thus you are facing the issue.

Simplest fix for this will be, to add another class with the same name and set the default margins and border like below, but add `!important` to the CSS property! so that it cannot be overridden by the same CSS present in `sematic.min.css`

```
.ui.segment[class*="bottom attached"]:last-child {
    margin-bottom:1rem !important;
}
```

I am writing this answer on the opinion that `sematic.min.css` need not be changed, else if you are open to modifying the `sematic.min.css` you just need to open the file in a text editor and set the values as above, but the `!important` is not required, as we are modifying at the source itself!

There seems to be very minor change, due to the CSS.

```
.ui.attached:not(.message) + .ui.attached.segment:not(.top) {
    border-top: none;
}
```

To fix this you need to go to `sematic.min.css` and remove this CSS styling.

But its a very minor change and can be ignored I guess!

Comment: Hey, sorry to disturb you, I have another "kind of issue", do you know any solutions to separate the "Welcome" from the box, so when the box gets resized the "Welcome" stays in his place ?

Comment: My issue was with the slight jump that can be noticed in your fiddle. My OCD wanted that misalignment fixed. I fixed it with a `border-top: none` on the `ui bottom attached active tab segment` element.